# iOS forward geocoding block not being executed

Tags: iphone, ios, geocoding, objective-c-blocks

Why this block of code isn't being executed? I copied and pasted it from another project of mine, where it works just fine. I also tried it in my other app with the same `addressString` I'm plugging in here, and it worked perfectly.

```
    NSString *addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ and %@, %@, NY", street, rightBound, [boroughs objectForKey:borough]];
    NSLog(@"Address string: %@",addressString);

    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressString completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Placemark count:%d",[placemarks count]);

        for(CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",placemark);
        }

        if(anError)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
        }
    }];
```

Neither any placemarks nor an error message is logged to the console.

Here is my entire AppDelegate.m:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

    NSString *JSONString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Streets" ofType:@"json"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
        NSLog(@"Break");
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithString:JSONString error:&error];
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
        NSLog(@"Break");
    }

    NSArray *addresses = [[dict objectForKey:@"results"] retain];

    NSDictionary *boroughs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bronx",@"Brooklyn",@"New York", @"Queens",@"Staten Island",nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"B",@"K",@"M",@"Q",@"S", nil]];

    int i = 1;
    for(NSDictionary *file in addresses)
    {
        NSString *borough = [file objectForKey:@"Borough"];
        NSString *ID = [file objectForKey:@"ID"];
        NSString *leftBound = [file objectForKey:@"LeftBound"];
        NSString *rightBound = [file objectForKey:@"RightBound"];
        NSString *sideOfStreet = [file objectForKey:@"SideOfStreet"];
        NSString *street = [file objectForKey:@"Street"];

        NSString *addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ and %@, %@, NY", street, rightBound, [boroughs objectForKey:borough]];
//        NSLog(@"Address string: %@",addressString);

        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

        [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressString completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *anError)
        {
            NSLog(@"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
            NSLog(@"Placemark count:%d",[placemarks count]);

            for(CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks)
            {
                NSLog(@"Placemark: %@",placemark);
            }

            if(anError)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
            }
        }];

        [geocoder release];
        NSLog(@"%d",i++);
    }
    [parser release];
    [addresses release];

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
        if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"geocoder"])
        {
            NSLog(@"AAAAAAA");
        }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure your "geocoder" instance is not nil?
Nothing will happen if you send a message to a "nil" object... :)

```
NSLog(@"%@",geocoder);
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately when I log the geocoder I get: `Geocoder: <CLGeocoder: 0x683bb00>`

Comment: Shame, make sure you have an internet connection? Make sure you are not attempting to initiate another forward or reverse geocoding request using the same geocoder, try with Apple's example addressString "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA"...

Comment: Definitely have an internet connection, am not making multiple requests at once, and tried with the example string. None of it worked! Which is really weird because it works in my other app...

Comment: Out of interest, could you use KVO to detect changes in your geocoder's "isGeocoding" property? NSLog() to see if/when it occurs...

Comment: No luck as in "no change observed", or no luck as in "change observed, but block still not called"? This is a really weird one!

Comment: No luck as in no changed observed. And I know! I'm calling all this in the app delegate. I'm wondering if I have to call it from a view controller? Or something that's not the app delegate, anyway. I'm basically writing a script and using iOS geocoding because there's no query limit (as far as I know).

Comment: Wow! Seriously? Ok, well, I don't think it'd need a View Controller, because it doesn't interact with views. Ok, well you've definitely imported the CoreLocation framework? Simulator or device?

Comment: It might be a long shot, but have you tried setting the simulator location? Debug menu > Location > Apple? I know we're not actually using your location, but because CLGeocoder works forwards and backwards, it might seize up if it cannot get location data...

Comment: If you have access to a device, I'd try that. If you don't, throw your app delegate up, and I'll take a look.

Comment: Setting the location didn't work. Will post the app delegate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what's going on. I ran the following code (original code minus the JSON operations) on my simulator and it worked perfectly. Maybe you need a fresh install of Xcode & iOS Simulator?

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSString *addressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA"];

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressString completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *anError)
     {
         NSLog(@"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
         NSLog(@"Placemark count:%d",[placemarks count]);

         for(CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks)
         {
             NSLog(@"Placemark: %@",placemark);
         }

         if(anError)
         {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@",[anError description]);
         }
     }];

    [geocoder release];

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Output was:

```
2011-12-21 18:56:30.311 Test[44445:f803] AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
2011-12-21 18:56:30.312 Test[44445:f803] Placemark count:1
2011-12-21 18:56:30.314 Test[44445:f803] Placemark: 1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA  95014-2083, United States @ <+37.33168400,-122.03075800> +/- 100.00m, region (identifier <+37.33168400,-122.03075800> radius 71.01) <+37.33168400,-122.03075800> radius 71.01m
```

The only thing I can think of is that you may be releasing your geocoder too early! Maybe try moving the release into the block? This way, you'll know the geocoder is only being released once after it has finished the geocode operation.

Also, you made a mistake with your error handling inside the block.
It should be `NSLog(@"Error: %@",[anError description]);`
instead of `NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);`.

Also, make sure you're not using ARC...

Comment: Tried uninstalling and reinstalling XCode, no luck. Not using ARC, including Core Location, etc., no luck still.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the reason this doesn't work is you cannot make multiple forward requests simultaneously. You must check the property isGeocoding before sending another one.